How to read all certificates one file is signed with?
I was looking for a Powershell script to read all certificates one file is signed with.
Powershell itself allows only reading the first certificate of a file via the default command. See my solution for this problem in the answer.

Here is my sample code I made for this. Enjoy!
cls
Remove-Variable * -ea 0
$errorActionPreference = 'stop'

$path = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\DRIVERS\fbwwanfilter.sys"

$reader = $null
try {
    # Open the file as a BinaryReader
    $reader = [System.IO.BinaryReader]::new([System.IO.File]::OpenRead($path))

    # Read DOS header:
    $null = $reader.BaseStream.Seek(0x3C, 0)
    $peHeaderOffset = $reader.ReadUInt32()

    # Read PE signature:
    $null = $reader.BaseStream.Seek($peHeaderOffset, 0)
    $signature = $reader.ReadUInt32()
    if ($signature -ne 0x4550) { throw "Not a PE file" }

    # Read the PE magic:
    $null = $reader.BaseStream.Seek(20, 1)
    $magic = $reader.ReadUInt16()

    $seekOffset = if ($magic -eq 0x10b) { 126 } elseif ($magic -eq 0x20b) { 142 } else { throw "Unknown PE magic" }
    $null = $reader.BaseStream.Seek($seekOffset, 1)

    # Read Certificate Table entry in Data Directory:
    $certStart = $reader.ReadUInt32()
    $certSize = $reader.ReadUInt32()
    if ($certStart -eq 0 -or $certSize -eq 0) { throw "No Certificate Table entry" }

    # Read Certificate Table
    $null = $reader.BaseStream.Seek($certStart, 0)
    $len = $reader.ReadUInt32()
    if ($len -eq 0) { throw "Certificate length is zero" }

    $revision = $reader.ReadUInt16()
    $certificateType = $reader.ReadUInt16()
    $certBytes = $reader.ReadBytes($len - 8)

    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
    $signedCms = [Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms]::new()
    $signedCms.Decode($certBytes)

    # Output certificate details
    $signedCms.Certificates
}
finally {
    if ($reader -ne $null) {
        $reader.Close()
    }
}

